# angular get data from literal array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

trying to extract data from literal array but I am doing something wrong as it does not work.

```
$http.get('/api/user/' + $routeParams.id)
      .then(function (res) {

       var user = res.data.message;
       console.log(user)

       }, function (err) {
             console.log(err);
       })
```

the code above gives me array as below:

```
[{"id": "1", "name": "user1"}]
```

I tried to get the data as below, but it did not work

```
vm.user = user.id;
//or
vm.user = user[0].id;
```

when I do

```
console.log(user[0]);
```

I get "[" as output

what am I doing wrong ? do I need to use loop ?

Comment: if the array is called "user" and contains the data you describe it user[0].id should work....

Comment: `user[0].id` should work. What do you get if you do `console.log(user[0].id)`?

Comment: `vm.user = user[0].id` should work. Can we get a little more info about why it is not working?

Comment: when I add console.log(user[0].id), I get undefined

Comment: and when I do console.log(user[0]) I get "[" as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a console output of `[{"id": "1", "name": "user1"}]` (from your code) gives you "[", then you don't have an array ... you have a string. Strings can be accessed by indexes, so:

`"TEST"[0] == "T", "TEST"[1] == "E"`- and so on

If that's the case, then you need to parse your string into an array of json objects - which you can do with JSON.parse ala:

`var userArray = JSON.parse(user);`

It may be that your API is returning a string instead of a JSON'ified object, but it's hard to know based on the detail you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

change
var user = res.data.message;

to

var user = res.data;

then 
console.log(user[0]);

To print it out.

also note that vm.user and user are two different variables make sure you're printing the one you're binding the data to.

Comment: it does not work, it's undefined...data is returned in message

Comment: Are you returning the data from a factory or are you doing it in the controller? Please show some more code.

Comment: in a controller

Comment: instead of doing this

var user = res.data.message;

do 
vm.user = res.data;

then

console.log(vm.user[0]);